# How do I find available parameters of an exe file?

Tags: visual-c++, parameters, exe

I have an exe file that accpets parameters. For example,

a.exe parameter1 parameter2 parameter3

the problem is that I am not sure what parameters areavailable. Is there a way to find out it? the exe is complied by visual c++.

Thanks.

Comment: if you're lucky, the program may accepts the `?` or `help` as a parameter and outputs a list of all available parameter combos.

Comment: I tried to find its documentation, enter ? or help. Both of them didn't work.

Comment: I really wish there was a standard for a section of metadata to describe parameters, then we could even have automatic tab-completion of parameters by the shell.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/736440/i-cant-get-command-line-parameters-of-exe-file
There is a good anwser.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is to query the parameters by passing a question mark:

```
c:\>myprogram.exe /?
```

and the application will display the available command line parameters. But there is nothing to force the application developers to do this, if they haven't then the best you can do is either read the doco, or disassemble it and look at the behaviour around the entry point of the app.

If the parameters are not published, then you should treat any you find as volatile and unreliable, liable to change anytime the developer wants to change them.